# Can I make 4x4 multiplier only using 2x2 multiplier?

Tags: verilog, vlsi

I want to implement to 4x4 bits multiplier using only 2x2 bits multiplier.

for example,
a=1110
b=1011
The 2x2 result is should be 10011010.

I think that I can split like this.

```
#case 1
a=10
b=11
2x2 multiplier's result = 0110

#case 2
a=11
b=10
2x2 multiplier's result = 0110
```

I can get the 2 result by using 2x2 multiplier.
but how can I make to 4x4 multiplier only using 2x2 multiplier?

But I can't approch to any hint. So how can I make 4x4 multiplier. Does anyone know how to do this? Please help.

In brief, How many 4x4 multiplier would you need to perform an 8x8 multiply.
how an 8x8 multiplier would be created using only 4x4 multipliers?

Update :

Is this working?
 http://blog.pioneermathematics.com/2011/04/26/vedic-trick-on-multiplication/ How ?

Comment: That's basically a math problem.

Comment: Convert after the multiplication?

Comment: Do you have addition or just multiplication?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks.  just multiplication

Comment: What other building blocks are available? You need at least wiring and registers and clock-related stuff.

Comment: @EvanCarslake what do you mean ?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev.  Yes wiring and registers available.

Comment: Well, any shift or accumulating registers?
Hmm... I think one can make an accumulator of a regular register by wiring it to itself.

Comment: @Morgan Sir Would you please help me? I think it should be need 2 4x4 multiplier to make 8x8 multiplier. But I can get prove this.

Comment: ..Not really. For a accumulator, edge-triggered logic gates are needed as well. Are these available?

Comment: @kaji: imho at least 4.

Comment: @Qiu thank but how do you prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See lvds answer on [how to cascade multipliers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28452943/97073).

### Some other points on Multipliers

Bare in mind as the input bit width grows to a multiplier, the multiplier size grows exponentially, therefore this is not a linear problem.

Multipliers can be considered to be a sum of shifts, if each shift is controlled by the position and value of the multiplicand we can build a multiplier out of shifts and some AND gates.

```
reg [3:0] a;
reg [3:0] b;
reg [7:0] mul;

always @* begin
  // mul = a * b;
  mul = ((a << 3) & {4{b[3]}} )
      + ((a << 2) & {4{b[2]}} )
      + ((a << 1) & {4{b[1]}} )
      + ((a     ) & {4{b[0]}} );
end
```

Comment: Dear Morgan I found some posting here http://blog.pioneermathematics.com/2011/04/26/vedic-trick-on-multiplication/ but I am not sure is this working? How?

Comment: Sir, is this apply to algebra boolean equation? Can we exchange to algebra boolean equation from above 4x4 binary multiplication? How about this idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2x2->4 multipliers, you get 4x4->8 multiplier like this:

```
wire [3:0] a; // multiplicands
wire [3:0] b; //

wire [3:0] lr;  // partial products
wire [3:0] mr1; //
wire [3:0] mr2; //
wire [3:0] hr;  //

wire [7:0] result; // resulting full product

assign lr  = a[1:0]*b[1:0]; // lowest 4bit partial product
assign mr1 = a[3:2]*b[1:0]; // middle one
assign mr2 = a[1:0]*b[3:2]; // another middle one
assign hr  = a[3:2]*b[3:2]; // highest one

// combine partial products into final product
assign result = {4'd0,lr} + {2'd0,mr1,2'd0} + {2'd0,mr2,2'd0} + {hr,4'd0};
```

There are also more sophisticated ways to multiply full numbers by multiplying parts of numbers, for example [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), but they are probably useless for hardware multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. if you can, would you please show how an 8x8 multiplier would be created using only 4x4 multipliers?

Comment: @kaji, you should be able to spot the pattern here. 8x8 will take **4** 4x4. It will always take 4 to double the input widths. The LSBs, MSBs the LSB of each against the MSB of the others.

Comment: @lvd impressive, not seen multipliers cascaded like this to make larger ones. We could insert flip-flops between stages to make multi-cycle pipelined multipliers.